# C# WPF Displaying and loading indicator while the UI is Blocked

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I've been reading through lots of Posts here lately to find a solution for my problem but neighter of them semed to work....

So here's my Problem:
I have a long loading function where I go through along list of Object for a few times. (Mostly because I'll have to find Children and Children of Children...)

This Funktion works for the most part, but it get is kind of slow, even though I've tried to use threads as much as I could and pre loading huge DataTables.

The biggest Problem is, that I generate UserControls, that generate more UserControls casuled into each other.

Mabe This will help:
- Itterate through all objects, and find the ones with parent = null
- Then go though all the "childs" with parent = null and insert them into a scrollviewer
- Each inserted child will search for it's own children and generate another overview over them into a stackPanel in it's own element.

All these rendering/calculations take some time and while it's running, the user sees a grey window, because I'm calling this function in my "Window.loaded()" function.

What I want now to do is, display a ring, or Image and maybe rotate it while all these Graphical elements are beeing added to the main Window.

```
private void getData() {
LoadingMessage lm = new LoadingMessage() { Owner = this };
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { lm.Show(); });
tbLoading.Text += ".";
//dtRacks = Storage.getAllNormalRacks();
//DataTable dtparents = dtRacks.AsDataView().ToTable(true, "CONTENTOF");
bool hasRacks = false;

start = Storage.getStorageObject(parentID);

spRooms.Children.Clear();
tbHeader.Text = "Übersicht: " + start["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();


DataTable dtchilds = getChilds(parentID);

foreach (DataRow dr in dtchilds.Rows) {
    string type = dr["TYPE"].ToString();

    if (type == "8") {
        RoomOverview ro = new RoomOverview(dr["ID"].ToString(), dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString(), search, this);
        foreach (Expander ex in ro.MainGrid.Children.OfType<Expander>()) {
            ex.IsExpanded = true;
        }
        ro.Padding = new Thickness(3, 0, 1, 0);
        if (ro.spFridges.Children.Count >= 1) spRooms.Children.Add(ro);

    }

    if (type == "1" || type == "2" || type == "3" || type == "4") {
        RefrigeratorOverview ro = new RefrigeratorOverview(dr["ID"].ToString(), dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString(), search, this);
        ro.Padding = new Thickness(3, 0, 1, 0);
        if (ro.spStudies.Children.Count >= 1) spRooms.Children.Add(ro);
    }
    if (type == "5") hasRacks = true;
}

if (hasRacks) {
    RefrigeratorOverview ro = new RefrigeratorOverview(parentID, start["DESCRIPTION"].ToString(), search);
    ro.Padding = new Thickness(3, 0, 1, 0);
    if (ro.spStudies.Children.Count >= 1) spRooms.Children.Add(ro);
}

if (roots.Count > 0) {
    foreach (string s in roots) {
        RoomOverview ro = new RoomOverview(s, null, search, this);
        ro.Padding = new Thickness(3, 0, 1, 0);
        if (ro.spFridges.Children.Count >= 1) spRooms.Children.Add(ro);

    }
    tbLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { lm.Close(); });
}
}
```

I tried putting this whole function into a Threaded function, but then my calls on "RoomOverview ro = new RoomOverview" and "RefrigeratorOverview ro = new RefrigeratorOverview" gave me an error because they can't add anything to the main form, because it belongs to another thread.

I'd hope that anyone understands what I'm trying to do here and hopefully knows a solution.


Best regards 
Alex

Comment: I would say - not being rude - that you are on the very wrong way nanipulating the gui elements to get data and make processing....you must go through MVVM and manipulate the model and/or view model, not the view...

Comment: There are tons of solutions for this, and I'm wondering why they all didn't work for you. First of all, you are in the WPF world (welcome!), so **please** don't create your UI in the code. Use XAML and MVVM techniques. This will solve all the threading issues for you, and you can easily add some busy indicators or similar things to your app.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually new to WPF and don't know much about MVVM but I'll definitly try to look into it more.
I'm probably not going to refactor my whole project now (it's grown really fast) but for the future I might try to get a better MVVM model going. :-)
Thanks for your Comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `RoomOverview` and `RefrigeratorOverview` are controls. If so, that's not a good way to use WPF. Please consider learning MVVM. It makes this kind of thing much easier. It's very painful to have to deal with code that mixes database stuff and UI controls. Ideally, you should write a method that does the database stuff and returns a collection of plain C# class instances. Then you put those in an `ObservableCollection` bound to an `ItemsControl` or something, with a `DataTemplate` that creates all the UI controls for you.

But if you don't want to go through that redesign, you can salvage what you've got.

Put all your process in another thread, as you tried to do.

Then to touch the controls in the UI thread, you'll need to "invoke into the UI thread", which means that from inside your worker thread, you can cause code to be executed in the UI thread:

```
RoomOverview ro = null;
var id = dr["ID"].ToString();
var description = dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    ro = new RoomOverview(id, description, search, this);
    foreach (Expander ex in ro.MainGrid.Children.OfType<Expander>()) {
        ex.IsExpanded = true;
    }
    ro.Padding = new Thickness(3, 0, 1, 0);
    if (ro.spFridges.Children.Count >= 1) spRooms.Children.Add(ro);
}));
```

Comment: Thank you @EdPlunkett that helped me. It's not perfect and I guess it's my fault  and my way of coding that it's not workling like I think it "should" but at least the gui loads now before the data (or while) is loaded.
So I just made an label with "loading data..." and displayed it. And after I'm finished loading, I disable it again.